# How to sort a list of Classes

Tags: c#, winforms, list, linq, sorting

I have a class called DataStore and in that i have the following;

```
string Name;
DateTime Date;
double Code;
```

In the main form i have the list below;

```
List<DataStore> ListOfDataStore = new List<DataStore>
```

I create instances of this class in the main form and assign values from what the user inputs and store them in the list below;

```
 DataStore dataStore = new DataStore();
 dataStore.Name = "abc";
 dataStore.Date = new DateTime(Year,Month,Day);
 dataStore.Code = 10;
 ListOfDataStore.Add(dataStore);

 DataStore dataStore = new DataStore();
 dataStore.Name = "def";
 dataStore.Date = new DateTime(Year,Month,Day);
 dataStore.Code = 20;
 ListOfDataStore.Add(dataStore);

 DataStore dataStore = new DataStore();
 dataStore.Name = "ghi";
 dataStore.Date = new DateTime(Year,Month,Day);
 dataStore.Code = 30;
 ListOfDataStore.Add(dataStore);
```

I now want to sort ListOfDataStore by what is in each of the `dataStore.Name`but I cant work out how to access the string Name without giving an index of the list ListOfDataStore.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort the list in place:

```
ListOfDataStore.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

If you want a new collection ordered by name:

```
var orderedListOfDataStore = ListOfDataStore.OrderBy(item => item.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

LinQ can help you to order a list with the method [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) or [OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb548916(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var sorted = ListOfDataStore.OrderBy(d=> d.Name)
```